# Why does one method for allocating memory fail compared to another that works?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

If my intention was to create a dynamically sized array of structs. Could someone explain to me how one method that allocates memory to resize the array works the way it should; compared to one that fails after x number of elements are added to the array?

The following method uses `malloc()` (incorrectly). Could someone explain how to properly allocate memory to the array?

```
struct some_struct{...data members...}*collection = NULL;
    int total_elements;
    int space_allocated; // the number of elements allocated to the array

    void resize_array(){
        if(total_elements == space_allocated) {
            if(space_allocated == 0)
                space_allocated =2;
            else
                space_allocated *= 2;
            //where collection is a pointer to a struct
            collection = malloc(space_allocated * sizeof(struct some_struct));

            if(collection == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"NO MEMORY ALLOCATED");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Compared to another method that uses `realloc()` correctly to dynamically allocate memory for the array. What is the significance of a void* type variable used to hold the memory?

```
    void resize_array(){

        if(total_elements == space_allocated){
            if(space_allocated == 0)
                space_allocated = 2;
            else
                space_allocated *= 2;
                //why is a variable of type void allowed? What does that mean?
                void* tmp = realloc(collection, ((num_allocated)*
                sizeof(struct some_struct)));
                if(!_tmp){
                    fprintf(stderr,"NO MEMORY ALLOCATED");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                //what is the significance of the pointer cast?
                collection = (some_struct*) _tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The pointer cast is not needed in C, as `void *` is implicitly convertible to any other pointer. And `void *` is what both [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) returns.

Comment: Also, if you follow [the `realloc` reference link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) you will see that if you pass a null pointer as the first argument then it works as `malloc`. So in your case it seems the correct solution would be the second function using `realloc`, even when doing the initial allocation (if `total_elements` and `space_allocated` are correctly initialized to zero).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude To your point about    `realloc()` functioning as    `malloc()` I did read about that somewhere on here. But what if I felt compelled to use just    `malloc()`?

Comment: Then perhaps create a separate (and simpler) function, like `create_array` which only allocates and initializes the variables.

Comment: The first function contains: `collection = malloc(space_allocated * sizeof(struct some_struct));

            if(course_collection == NULL){` — don't you need to check `collection` rather than `course_collection`?  It also throws away any previous data stored in `collection` — leaking memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fixed

Comment: While `space_allocated *= 2;` is fine, just note that doubling the allocation size can grow rapidly. Depending on your need adding a fixed amount (e.g. `space_allocated += CHUNK_SIZE;`) may serve your purposes better. It depends on your data. Obviously if you have 501k elements you don't want to resize to 1M at 500K.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Doubling is a very valid mechanism, and if you've already got 500 k elements, there's every chance you might get another 500 k of them unless there is some positive information to the contrary.  If you've finished reading and won't need to grow the array any more, and if there's more than some threshold of unused space (4 KiB, perhaps; perhaps less than that), then a shrinking `realloc()` will release the surplus space back to the storage management functions for later reused.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree, that's why I included "`space_allocated *= 2;` is fine". The note was just there for thought promotion over how one allocation scheme may better fit an anticipated data set than another. Not knocking either way. And you can always call a final `realloc` to size the allocation to your data after the input is over.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, Re "*Obviously if you have 501k elements you don't want to resize to 1M at 500K*", No, that's not obvious. Maybe growing by 100% is excessive, but the idea is sound. Perl arrays grow by 20%, so adding an element to a 500,000-element array extends the buffer to 600,000.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate the first initialization with `malloc`, and resize it with `realloc`.

When you `malloc` again in the first way(completely nonsense), the system allocate a NEW memory space and return the address. Now you made one good memory leak.

The second way looks logical, and remember, beside in some compilers, `realloc` could be used instead of `malloc`(where reallocating memory is `NULL`), but you may do the first initialization with `malloc` and ignore their kindness.

both `realloc` and `malloc` return `void*`, but at the end they all are bytes(`char`). Since C is well weaked, you may or may not cast the return type to a type(pointer). But in c++, it's diff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `void *` type, but I prefer to use the correct type

```
struct some_struct *tmp = realloc(collection, num_allocated * sizeof *tmp);
```

The temporary variable is used to avoid memory leaks in the error path:

```
if (!tmp) {
    perror("realloc()");
    free(collection);
    goto err;
}

collection = tmp;
```

You can always use `realloc()` when `collection` is initialized as `NULL`.  But you should verify that `num_allocated * sizeof *tmp` does not overflow.